# Receive Data from server asynchronously, with out Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I have been trying to send a message from grails service and show it in my web-page (receiver.gsp).

My service code is as follows:

```
public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                throws IOException {
            String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
            groovyPageRenderer.render view: '/receiver/receiver', model: [msg: message]
            println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
        }
```

My receiver.gsp page:

```
<div class="body">
<h1>Receiver</h1>

${msg}
```

I just want to show the message that is rendered from my Service asynchronously.

Every time my service is rendering msg, the value is caught in the receiver.gsp page, but it is not displayed.

Any hint or help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After the page leaves the server and is in browser you can't run any server side programming language in the browser, only javascript. If you want to get data asynchronously from server and update the dom use ajax

Comment: Then how does push notification works? Is there any other way of pushing data from server?

Comment: Push, in this sense, is something like web sockets. I recommend you look at what web sockets are and learn about them. Grails has several plugins that will help you once you understand how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `Service` to render your `View`?  I think you should use `Controller` to show what you want to display.

Comment: yes, we are suppose to use controller, but in my case, im trying to send message asynchronously, and this service would be called only once, when the application starts. so, i found it little impossible to render from controller.